# Getting errors from a method that already has a return type

Tags: c#, error-handling, single-responsibility-principle

I have a method that attempts to create a number of user accounts. If it was successful, it returns a list of the user IDs, otherwise I need to get a list of errors.  What's the best way to achieve this?

Here is a trimmed down version of what I've implemented:

```
public class RXGAdapter {

    private List<string> _errors;

    public IEnumerable<int> CreateAccounts(string username, int quantity) 
    {
        ResetErrors();

        var accountIDs = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) 
        {
            int accountID = CreateAccount(username + i);
            if (_errors.Count > 0)
            {
                return new List<int>();
            }
            accountIDs.Add(accountID);
        }
        return accountIDs;
    }

    public int CreateAccount(string username) 
    {
        try {
            // Make HTTP request to the server
            // Parse the ID from of the response if successful
            return id;
        }
        catch (WebException e) 
        {
            // Parse the errors from the response if unsuccessful
            _errors.AddRange(errors);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void ResetErrors() 
    {
        _errors = new List<string>();   
    }

    public bool HasErrors() 
    {
        return _errors.Count > 0;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Errors 
    {
        get { return _errors; }     
    }
}
```

I'm worried that this breaks the SRP though.

Comment: It's best to include relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Should I copy and paste it from Fiddler to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw a custom exception, containing the list of errors as a property of the custom exception.

Another way is, if you are allowed to alter the CreateAccounts function signature then you can return the status of each account creation in a list, as an out parameter for the CreateAccounts function.

Comment: I'm hesitant to throw an exception because it is normal for there to be errors (e.g. the username may already be taken).  Could you clarify what you mean by returning the status of each account creation in a list as an out parameter?

Comment: You can change the function like this.
public IEnumerable<int> CreateAccounts(string username, int quantity, out List<string> errors)
        {
            ResetErrors();
            errors = _errors;

            var accountIDs = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= quantity; i++)
            {
                int accountID = CreateAccount(username + i);
                if (_errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    return new List<int>();
                }
                accountIDs.Add(accountID);
            }
            return accountIDs;
        }